# Renaming and Saving Excel Files With Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I've got a pretty simple task but I haven't done too many functions with excel within python and I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

What I need to do:

Look at many excel files within subfolders, rename them according to information within the file and store them in all in one folder somewhere else.

The data is structured like this:

> Main Folder
>
> > Subfolder1
> >
> > > File1
> > >
> > > File2
> > >
> > > File3
> > >
> > > ...

For about a hundred subfolders and several files within each subfolder.

From here, I want to pull the company name, part number, and date from within the file and use those to rename the excel file. Not sure how to rename the file.

Then save it somewhere else. I'm having trouble finding all these functions, any advice?

Comment: Are you able to extract the company name, etc. from the file? i.e. is your question specifically about renaming or is it about getting the data from the file too? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [`os`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module for listing folder contents (`walk`, `listdir`) and working with path names (`abspath`, `basename` etc.)

Also, [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) has some interesting functions for copying stuff. Check out `copyfile` and specify the `dst` parameter based on the data you read from the excel file.

This page can help you getting at the Excel data: http://www.python-excel.org/

You probably want to have some highlevel code like this:

```
for subfolder_name in os.listdir(MAIN_FOLDER):
    # exercise left to reader: filter out non-folders
    subfolder_path = os.path.join(MAIN_FOLDER, subfolder_name)
    for excel_file_name in os.listdir(os.path.join(MAIN_FOLDER, subfolder_name)):
        # exercise left to reader: filter out non-excel-files
        excel_file_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, excel_file_name)
        new_excel_file_name = extract_filename_from_excel_file(excel_file_path)
        new_excel_file_path = os.path.join(NEW_MAIN_FOLDER, subfolder_name, 
            new_excel_file_name)
        shutil.copyfile(excel_file_path, new_excel_file_path)
```

You'll have to provide `extract_filename_from_excel_file` yourself using the `xlrd` module from the site I mentioned.

Comment: Looks good - I'm writing it now. One question:
In "for excel_file_name in os.list..." is the 'subfolder' subfolder_name or subfolder_path?

Comment: I'm also having trouble figuring out xlrd. Any suggestions?

Comment: FTFY: it is the `subfolder_name`. As for  `xlrd`, I don't have much experience myself. Look into a tutorial like this: http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2012/03/examples-reading-excel-xls-documents-using-pythons-xlrd/